# Auto update using firebase or parse?

Tags: mysql, database, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to update data every one hour automatically?

For example ,

```
    CREATE EVENT reset
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
        DO
update T1 
set state=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mysql event

----------example event syntax --------

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: you can find more details from above link